# Compile function showing error in custom directive angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image: CustomDirective code to understand compile and link]

At the bottom window, JS stops scanning and gives the statement as "too many errors". I cross checked the code multiple times from the lectures I am learning from and from many other sites. But it still doesn't work..

Comment: an image of code is great, but in the future copy/paste your actual code into the text of your question.

Comment: Jhecht .. well sorry for that .. i was in a hurry, so i just took a snip this time.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a closing `}` in your return statement.

Comment: Thanks .. Didn't see that actually